# Searching HTML using Google

Tags: javascript, html, search

I'm trying to make the `Search` function on my website work using Google. Below is the HTML:

```
<!-- Start Search -->
<div class="top-search">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <span class="input-group-addon close-search"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Search -->
```

The JS:

```
<!-- Search JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form-control').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:mywebsite.co.uk ' + document.getElementById('search').value;
    return false;
}
</script>
<!-- End Search Javascript -->
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You may want to change your `input`  `type` to `search`

Comment: @JosanIracheta It doesn't search, When I press enter nothing happens

Comment: @ClaudioCortese I'll do that

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't have a form. Wrap your input element in a form and it will submit

Comment: @JosanIracheta Thank you. How do I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @Adam you can mark my answer correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<form>` element in order for the `onsubmit` event to be triggered. Wrap the `<input>` element in a form and it will work.

```
<form>
<!-- Start Search -->
<div class="top-search">
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-addon close-search"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Search -->
</form>
```